# Is the electric field of a volume charge distribution well defined?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider a volume charge distribution $\rho({\bf r'})$. The electric field at ${\bf r}$ is

$${\bf E}({\bf r})=\iiint\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\rho({\bf r'})}{R^2}\hat{\bf R}d^3{\bf r'}$$

where ${\bf R}={\bf r}-{\bf r'}$.

My question is at positions ${\bf r}$ where $\rho \ne 0$, the integrand blows up when ${\bf R}={\bf 0}$. But I know from EM textbooks that ${\bf E}({\bf r})$ at where $\rho({\bf r})\ne 0$ is well-defined.

Can one explain this mathematically?

Comment: **HINT**: Look up *Dirac-delta function*.

Comment: In the regime $R \approx 0$ (i.e., $\rho$ is close to a point mass at $r$), you're no longer doing classical EM. As for the integral itself, though, the integral can still converge as long as $\rho$ decays sufficiently quickly near $R = 0$.

Comment: I guess $\hat{\mathbf{R}}$ is the unit vector in the direction of $\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'$? If $\rho$ is bounded - or even just doesn't grow too fast - near $\mathbf{r}$, then the integrand has an integrable singularity at $\mathbf{r}$. $$\int_{\lVert x\rVert < 1} \lVert x\rVert^{-\alpha}\,d^nx < +\infty \iff \alpha < n.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Then does it mean that for a surface/line charge distribution, the E field on the surface/line is undefined?

Comment: Umm. Physically, there is no such thing as a surface/line charge distribution, as far as I know. It's an abstraction/idealisation for very thin charge distributions, isn't it? If the integrand is the same, the integral will not exist (on the surface/line) in the Lebesgue sense if you integrate over a surface or line, but there will be cancellation due to the direction of the integrand, so that typically the integral will have a well-defined principal value. That would then be the field on the surface/line, I'd expect.

Comment: @DanielFischer By integrable singularity do you mean $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon<||x||<1}||x||^{-\alpha}d^n x < +\infty \iff \alpha < n$?